# laravel validation Array to string conversion error

Tags: laravel

if I check min|max before exist 
laravel validation will return Array to string conversion error.
(laravel version 5.5)

```php
return [
    // 'nick_name' => 'exists:users|max:150|min:6|regex:/\A[0-9a-zA-Z_]{6,150}\z/',
    'nick_name' => ['max:150', 'min:6', 'exists:users', 'regex:/\A[0-9a-zA-Z_]{6,150}\z/'],//return Array to string conversion error
    // 'nick_name' => ['exists:users', 'max:150', 'min:6', 'regex:/\A[0-9a-zA-Z_]{6,150}\z/'],//success
    'ref_code' => 'exists:users',
]
```

Comment: what  is actual your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you change your application language? If you have translation and translation is missing you can get this error. Just change app language to en and try again.

Comment: the language is `en` ,but It's laravel 5.5 not latest

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `nick_name` is string. Not an array

Make sure input field name is like shown below

```
<input type='text' name='nick_name' />  //if name='nick_name[]' then it will be an array 
//and below procedure will be used to validate it.
```

If it is array then validate it like shown below

```
nick_name.* => 'validation rule here'
```